# Class Identifiers Never Work?

Tags: c++, class, object, aggregation, abstract-data-type

I'm making a RoomDimension class that uses a FeetInches class, but whenever I use FeetInches inside of RoomDimension, I get an avalanche of error messages, including:

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'length'

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Here are the classes:

```
class FeetInches
{
private:
   int feet;        // To hold a number of feet
   int inches;      // To hold a number of inches

public:
   // Constructor
    FeetInches(int f = 0, int i = 0)
        { feet = f;
          inches = i; }

   // Mutator functions
    void setFeet(int f)
        { feet = f; }

    void setInches(int i)
        { inches = i; }

   // Accessor functions
    int getFeet() const
        { return feet; }

    int getInches() const
        { return inches; }

};

class RoomDimension
{
private:

    FeetInches length;
    FeetInches width;

public:

    // constructors
    RoomDimension(void);

    // getter functions
    FeetInches getLength(void) const
    { return length; }

    FeetInches getWidth(void) const
    { return width; }

    // setter functions
    void setLength(FeetInches l)
    { length = l; }

    void setWidth(FeetInches w)
    { width = w; }

};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sigh.  Which lines do the errors correspond to?

Comment: The code you posted compiles without error for me. If the errors are on some code you haven't shown us, then *show us that code*.

Comment: Compiles fine for me too.

Comment: You should post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) showing the problem. The above code compiles for me (it doesn't link, of course, as it is lacking a `main()`).

Comment: Unrelated: just make the fields public. Dumb getters and setters are pointless.

Comment: @KeithThompson Where do I put the code?

Comment: Click the "edit" link and update the question to include the code and the exact text of any error messages, clearly indicating which code lines the messages refer to. Try to eliminate anything that's not relevant to the problem. [Read this](http://sscce.org/) first. You should be able to narrow your code down to a few dozen lines (be very sure that the shortened version still produces the same errors).

Comment: @rightfold: Really; that's your advice - make them public? "getters and setters are pointless"?? Wow!

Comment: I figured it out.  I had a crazy network of #includetthisfile, and I fixed it.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Read my comment again. “_Dumb_ getters and setters are pointless.”

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any problem except that the constructor of `RoomDimension` is not implemented.

Comment: That would be a great comment, but it's not an answer. (The question is unanswerable in its current form.)

Comment: @SoloMael, Just as Keith said, please provide us with more information. Or if the code works fine now, close the topic.

Comment: Is there a way for me to send a file?  I could send the VC++ Project.

Comment: Just show us the context of the error and point the error line to us.

Comment: It's way too long for the comments

Comment: In your post, not comment.